# apache_beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery pass parameters dynamically in Dataflow pipeline templates

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am running a GCP Dataflow pipeline by deploying it as a template on GCP. I need to run a BigQuery read statement in the pipeline. The conditional parameter of which needs to be passed dynamically. How do I do so?

The query I want to run is something like

```
select * from tabel_name where field1=[dynamic_value]
```

Here is the sample code to run the query

```
    import apache_beam as beam
    query_string = "select * from tabel_name where field1=[dynamic_value]"

    options = {'project': PROJECT_ID, 'runner': 'Direct', "temp_location": "gs://my_bucket/temp",'region': "australia-southeast1", }
    pipeline_options = beam.pipeline.PipelineOptions(sys.argv,**options)
    custom_options = pipeline_options.view_as(MyOptions)

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        sample = (
                pipeline
                | 'QueryTable' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(query=query_string, use_standard_sql=False)
                | "Processing" >> beam.ParDo(MyPreprocessor())
                | beam.Map(print))
```

I need to pass the `dynamic_value` from a command line option `--dynamic_value`. I can pass it as a `sys.argv` parameter if it is not a template, however if I deploy a template it expects the `dynamic_value` as a PipelineOption. How do I dynamically create the query?
Surprisingly the method `beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery` has a mechanism of taking a dataset, project_id and table as parameters but does not have any parameter where we can specify a filter for the data. Querying the entire table is un-necessary and expensive. Can someone provide a solution to the same.

Comment: Edit your question and show the template that matches your code. Read this link for tips on how to create good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you try to pass the dynamic_value as pipeline parameter, to get the valud in the pipeline_option and to build your query_string with it before starting your pipeline?

Comment: @guillaume-blaquiere if we pass it as a pipeline parameter then during template deploy it asks for the parameter to be present, which is not what we need. We need to pass the parameter at runtime. That cannot be processes directly as a string concatenation. As runtime value providers can be processed in ParDo's and the ReadFromBigQuery does not take side inputs so cant do a ParDo there.

Comment: Did you have a look to the valueprovider pattern? https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#python

Comment: Even if this thread is more than 2 years old: Just use a parametrizable string, for instance f"select ..... ={dynamic_value}"

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using [Flex Templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates) to support fully dynamic configuration of queries as a template.